# Spring Conversion Error displays internal exception over validator

Tags: java, spring, exception, type-conversion

So in my Spring application I have a text field that converts to a date in the model and the feild uses a jquery datepicker. If you type in a date manually that also works but when you enter a wrong date some weird stuff starts happening. My validator picks up most of the errors and displays a custom error message but when the month is 0, or the day is above the last day of the month, it displays the following error under the field in the form

[image]

but when you make most errors like go high with the month my validator will handle it but if the day is high or the month is low the validator gets trumped by Springs internal exception.

[image]
[image]

Is there some way to customize this error message WITHOUT using javascript and WITHOUT using the date type? The date type is probably the easiest solution but it messes with the datepicker that i use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making a properties file and using the typeMismatch. below is some of the code

in the i18n folder i made a text.properties then used the following

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/text" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
```

After this I added the line

```
typeMismatch.creationDate =Invalid Date format. Please use mm/dd/yyyy and make sure numbers are valid
```

into the text.properties file. This changed the error thrown by Spring to the one i specified